# boot parameter "acpi_osi= " disables USB ports

Tags: boot, usb, webcam, touchscreen, acpi

I freshly installed ubuntu in my Hp Pavllion 360, and could not boot without using

```
acpi=off
```

as boot parameter. As this turned off my battery management and Wifi, I tried a couple of other parameters instead and found

```
acpi_osi=
```

It turned on my WiFi and battery status, but disabled my USB ports, webcam and touchscreen.

I badly need my WiFi , USB ports and webcam up and running.
Is there any other parameters which could make this all work?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The bios settings for usb had to be changed from "auto" to "enable", keeping the boot parameter as "acpi_osi=".